# How can I change a .net executable's values using reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

I have a program that depends on a configuration file for three settings. I currently generate a new config file at download time for each version that's downloaded (it's the same executable but I fill in the configuration values that are appropriate on the download page and zip the exe and the config file for the purposes of providing a single download).

I'd like to use reflection to:

1.) Read in the .exe

2.) Change 3 string values

3.) Write out a new .exe with the new values

Is this possible? How would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: It may or may not be possible, but it's certainly not best practice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible using Reflection. Reflection can only inspect, not modify. There are other tools that might be able to do that like Mono.Cecil. But I think you are just designing it wrong. Values that should be changed should be stored outside the exe, in standalone .config file.

Another way is to build exe file before each download and pass values at build time. Anyway not good idea.